# PHP Storm and Option key in Mac

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, phpstorm

Looking for a way to fix the option key not working with PHP Storm and the Mac. I use things like:

- Option + Left or Right: Navigate to previous / next word.
- Option + Shift + Left or Right: Highlight previous / next word.
- Option + Backspace: Delete previous word.

Guessing this is a Java thing?

Comment: Do you use `Mac OS X` or `Mac OS X 10.5+` keymap in `Preferences` | `Keymaps`? What Look&Feel is set in `Appearance`? I've checked it with PhpStorm on Mac OS X 10.8.1 and shortcuts you mentioned work fine.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that the Keymaps section at the top existed. I installed the IdeaVim plugin which changed `Preferences` | `Keymaps` to Vim. Works great now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specified keyboard shortcuts work as described in `Mac OS X` and `Mac OS X 10.5+` keymaps. Keymap can be changed in `Preferences` | `Keymaps`.